# Use extern variable between 2 files (linux/windows) versions

Tags: c, extern

In my code I have an extern variable (test.h) - `extern int tmp;` - declaration, I also have two implementation files, for linux: `test_linux.c` and `test_windows.c`. There, I have a definition (`int tmp = 0;`), both in `test_linux.c` and `test_windows.c`. Of course, I have in both files checking: `#ifdef __WIN__` ... and `#ifdef __LIN__`...

When I try to compile it with gcc on linux, it somehow ''sees'' the variable declared both in `test_linux.c` and `test_windows.c`, but:

1. on linux, gcc should see the declaration only from `test_linux.c`,
2. and on windows, visual should only see the definition from `test_windows.c`

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

My `test.h` file:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void use_temp();

extern volatile int temp = 0;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

My `test_linux.c` file:

```
#include "test.h"

#if ((defined(__linux__) || defined(__gnu_linux) || defined(__linux)) && defined(__GNUC__))
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int temp = 0;

#endif

void use_temp()
{
    temp = 1024;
}
```

My `test_windows.c` file:

```
#include "test.h"

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#elif ((defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)) && (defined(_MSC_VER)))
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int temp = 0;

#endif


void use_temp()
{
    temp = 1024;
}
```

And errors:

```
$ gcc -g -c test_windows.c test_linux.c main.c 
In file included from test_windows.c:1:0:
test.h:10:21: warning: ‘temp’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
 extern volatile int temp = 0;
                     ^
In file included from test_linux.c:1:0:
test.h:10:21: warning: ‘temp’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
 extern volatile int temp = 0;
                     ^
test_linux.c:8:5: error: conflicting type qualifiers for ‘temp’
 int temp = 0;
     ^
In file included from test_linux.c:1:0:
test.h:10:21: note: previous definition of ‘temp’ was here
 extern volatile int temp = 0;
                     ^
In file included from main.c:1:0:
test.h:10:21: warning: ‘temp’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
 extern volatile int temp = 0;
```

Comment: You should rely on existing defines instead of creating your owns. Better, you could use a tool like CMake to exclude or include specific files depending on the platform it runs on.

Comment: @Chnossos: How can I do such thing? Where can I read about it? I don't even know what to type in in google, any advice? :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is perfectly achievable, you need to find the cause of the compilation error.

For starters, add a check at the beginning of one of the files, e.g.:

```
#if defined(__WIN__) && defined(__LIN__)
#error Only one OS should be defined
#endif
```

This will protect you from any present and future mistakes.

Comment: Ok, here's my `test.h` file: http://pastie.org/private/olnpdjylpvxvcx4azrdnxg, `test_linux.c` file: http://pastie.org/private/z6kgfzrbx2xvnco4yth0ea, and `test_windows.c` file: http://pastie.org/private/wonzb8ubjpl0jnugs4tw and the error: `error: conflicting type qualifiers for ‘temp’`